# Merge pdfs documents in one KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I'm trying to use KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle, I want to know if i can :

1. Merge pdf files in one
2. Convert images to pdf
3. Load pdf locally

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class PdfController extends AbstractController
{
    private $pdf;
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(Pdf $pdf, KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("pdf")
     */
    public function pdfAction()
    {
        $html = "<html><body>hello snappy !</body></html>";
        // trying to merge pdf -> error
        $this->pdf->generate(['http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf', 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'], 'merge.pdf');
        //trying to convert jpg to pdf -> it show empty PDF !
        $this->pdf->generate('https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/minion.jpg', 'jpgToPdf.pdf');
    }
}
```

Error :

> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading
>   pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [===> ] 5% [======> ] 10% Error: Failed loading
>   page http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf (sometimes it will work
>   just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore) Error:
>   Failed loading page http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
>   (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with
>   --load-error-handling ignore) Exit with code 1, due to unknown error. " stdout: "" command: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality
>   'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf'
>   'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf' 'merge.pdf'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle** provide tools to generate PDF from HTML, And also tools to generate Images.
we can look for an other tool to merge pdfs like **clegginabox/pdf-merger**
To convert pictures to PDF we can look for **Setasign/FPDF**